# Activity reference from C# to JNI

Tags: c#, android-activity, java-native-interface, xamarin.android, parse-platform

How it's possible to pass C# Activity reference to JNI in Xamarin Android?

I have my wrapper to jar that reference this method where I must pass a reference to my Activity (that is in Xamarin Android)

`PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(context, YourActivity.class);`

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling this within `YourActivity` you can use:

```
PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(context, this.Class);
```

else you need:

```
PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(context, (new YourActivity()).Class);
```

see: http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=P%3aJava.Lang.Object.Class I don't know, if there is an static way to get the Class.